# How to get f.select/options_for_select data when form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form where user's can select multiple contacts from a dropdown list.

**/emails/_form.html.slim**

```
= f.select :profiles, options_for_select(@project.contacts.map { |c| ["#{c.profile.name} (#{c.email})", c.profile.id] }), {}, multiple: :multiple, class: 'selectable form-control'
```

How do I pull the selected user(s) data into the controller, in order to display it in the /emails/show view?

Email to:
a@ex.com, b@ex.com, c@ex.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected values will be available as `params[:email][:profiles]` in your respected `controller#action`. Use it to construct a query which will fetch the users data with the respected ids, save those into an instance variable and use that instance variable to display the data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards an answer... although i needed something extra in my controller

      `if (params[:email][:profile_ids] rescue false)
        params[:email][:profile_ids].delete_if(&:blank?)
      end`

and now I can get the first selection, or second etc

`@email.profiles.first.profiled.email` # returns "person@place.com"
`@email.profiles.second.profiled.email` # returns "person2@place.com"